# Removing files in directory with special characters

Tags: php

I tried removing files in directory with special characters using php.

I used the `unlink()` function and it worked as it is, but when the file contains special chars, it can't locate the file.

Now I use `str_replace()` function to replace the name.

See example below.

```
<?php
   //replace "+" sign with space.
   $filename = str_replace("+", " ", $filename); 

   $dir = "_resources/docs/";
   unlink($dir . $filename);
?>
```

It works but how about files with a name like this? 
`[Vouching_Sample_02]-SMCC_Q3_Vouching_September_Goods_012216`.

Is there any good recommendations for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this kind of solution.

```
$name = "This-is_a__test--(name)";
$find = array("-", "_", "--", "(", ")");
$replace = array(" ", " ", " ", " ", " ");
$converted = str_replace($find, $replace, $name);

echo $converted;
```

Out put: This is a test name

Include what you want to search in fine array.

Include what you want to replace with in replace array.

Else use `preg_replace()` with regular expression

Comment: But how about brackets?

Comment: I have modified the answer

Comment: sorry but I wanted a more detailed answer.

Comment: your name is [Vouching_Sample_02]-SMCC_Q3_Vouching_September_Goods_012216 in the example, so include the [ in find array and replacement in the find array, sorry i didn't put the $converted = str_replace($find, $replace, $name); in answer. i have made the changes.

Comment: yes, but this will make the code untidy. I am now moving to rename the name first so that I will not be having a problem in removing them. thanks anyway for your help. I would accept this